# :CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I/flutter ( 7701): {name: mayank, password: mayank12}
E/flutter ( 7701): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
E/flutter ( 7701):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
E/flutter ( 7701):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import '../model/login_model.dart';

class APIService {
Future<LoginResponseModel> login(LoginRequestModel requestModel) async {

String url = "https://logistics.hub.com/mobile/req/staff-login/";
final response = await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(requestModel.toJson()),headers: {"content- 
type":"application/json"});
 print(response.body);
 if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 400) {
  return LoginResponseModel.fromJson(
    json.decode(response.body),
  );
    } else {
   throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: the URL ``https://logistics.hub.com/mobile/req/staff-login/`` is dead

Comment: the Url is for a example

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue here is that you need to setup the SSL config on the server-side, similar to the issue reported on this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50699#issuecomment-585893921).